# How to split a string with a numeric suffix?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have an input string and I need to split it according to the requirement below.

Input String :

```
  1. "string"
  2. "String 12343534"
  3. "String_12343534"
  4. "Stringone Stringtwo 12343534"
  5. "Stringone Stringtwo_12343534"
  6. "string 23string 12343534"
  7. "string 23string_12343534"
  8. "string_23string 12343534"
  9. "string_23string_12343534"
 10. "string 23string 4545stringthird 12343534"
 11. "string 23string 4545stringthird_12343534"
 12. "string_23string_stringthird_12343534"
 13. "string-23string-stringthird_12343534"
 14. "string_23string-stringthird_12343534"
```

Like this going on. And **I have to split string separately and numerical separately**.

The output should like this.

```
   1.  $str = "string" ; $num = ;
   2.  $str = "String" $num = "12343534";
   3.  $str = "String" $num = "_12343534";
   4.  $str = "Stringone Stringtwo" $num = "12343534";
   5.  $str = "Stringone Stringtwo" $num = "_12343534";
   6.  $str = "string 23string" $num = "12343534";
   7.  $str = "string 23string" $num = "_12343534";
   8.  $str = "string_23string" $num = "12343534";
   9.  $str = "string_23string" $num = "_12343534";
  10.  $str = "string 23string 4545stringthird" $num = "12343534";
  11.  $str = "string 23string 4545stringthird" $num = "_12343534";
  12.  $str = "string_23string_stringthird" $num = "_12343534";
  13.  $str = "string-23string-stringthird" $num = "_12343534";
  14.  $str = "string_23string-stringthird" $num = "_12343534";
```

Anyone can help me on this? How to split the given string to get above mentioned output?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to keep everything, you have to split on an anchor point. You can use a lookahead for this. Split on the following pattern:

```
(?=_\d)|\s+(?=\d)
```

So:

```
my ($string, $numerical) = split /(?=_\d)|\s+(?=\d)/, $input;
```

If an underscore is present before the digits, it will split just before it, otherwise it will split on any whitespace followed by a digit. This is the translation of the regex.

You could also use the following:

```
(?=_\d+$)|\s+(?=\d+$)
```

This will ensure there's nothing after the digits by forcing the match to go to the end of the string. If there's a non-digit character at the end, the split won't happen.

But it's easier to just match what you need instead of splitting IMO:

```
my ($string, $numerical) = $input =~ /^(.*?)\s*(_?\d+)$/;
```

This is more readable and better conveys your intent.

Comment: Could you pls explain this expression how did you make ?

Comment: @saravanakumar I tried to add some explanations, but these regexes are rather simple, so I encourage you to read some regex tutorials - once you do you'll be able to write this sort of expressions in no time.

Comment: Thankyou @Lucas Trzesniewski. Can you pls give me some online tutorial site for regrex.

Comment: @saravanakumar I can't recommend you any online tutorials, but there are many of them, Google is your friend. If you want to get serious with regexes though, I can recommend you [this book](http://regex.info/book.html), which is basically the best reference you'll be able to find.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find the solutions using `split` a little overcomplex, and none of them seem to cope with a string like:

```
my $input = "code 4 you 12345678";
```

... where I'd expect the numeric suffix to be 12345678, not "4" or "4 you".

I'd prefer something like:

```
my ($string, $numerical) = $input =~ /^ (.+?) \s* (_?\d+) $/x;
```

**Update:** I think my solution above already covers most of your updated examples: all but the first example where the numeric suffix is empty. To cover the first example, you also need to set `$string` to the entire input string when the regexp fails to match at all. Something like this:

```
my ($string, $numerical) = ($input =~ /^ (.+?) \s* (_?\d+) $/x) ? ($1, $2) : ($input);
```

Comment: I have updated requirement (mentioned above) and i want to change the regex according to that. How can i change ?

Comment: Updated to cover your extra requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code ,

```
my ($string, $numerical) = split / (?=\d+)|(?=_\d+)/, $str;
```

`(?=_\d+)` called positive lookahead which asserts what follows is an underscore followed by one or more numbers. If this condition is true then the regex engine sets the matching marker just before to the `_\d+`. Splitting according to this zero width match will give you the desired results.

Comment: @saravanakumar accept anyone of the answers here if it's more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on the boundary between numerical and alpha characters, you need to use [positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind).

The additional spec for deciding where to include underscores is not entirely clear, but this is my best interpretation of what your intent may be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split m{(?<=[a-z])\s*(?=_*\d)|(?<=\d)\s*(?=_*[a-z])}i, $_;

    use Data::Dump;
    dd @fields;
}

__DATA__
string 123456
string_45645645
stringone stringtwo 23435345345
string one string two_2335345345
```

Outputs:

```
("string", 123456)
("string", "_45645645")
("stringone stringtwo", 23435345345)
("string one string two", "_2335345345")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z\s]*)(.*)$
```

This will work.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rX0dM7/8